# different outputs in c

Tags: c, output

these 4 programs all create an array with 10000 char elements and all have a different output. can anyone explain why ?

number 1:

```
int main()
{
char buffer[10000];
printf("address: %p\n", buffer);
return 0;
}
```

number 2:

```
char buffer[10000];

int main()
{
    printf("address: %p\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

number 3:

```
char buffer[10000] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
int main()
{
    printf("address: %p\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

number 4:

```
int main()
{
    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(10000);
    printf("address: %p\n", buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%p` prints out the address of `buffer` in memory. Why would you expect it to be the same every time you run the program?

Comment: You actually try to ask about different linking schemes for variables, don't you?

Comment: How much do you know about different memories for variables? Do you know the meaning of "local", "global", "dynamic", "bss", "data", "explicitly initialised"? can you use those terms to describe the differences between your programs? Do you know about how much of those is actually mentioned in C standard?

Answer (score 1):

The reason, as others have touched on, is that the address of the buffer is
printed and it isn't always the same. The question though, is why?

To answer this lets make a guess at where the compiler will put the buffer in
each case.

As background, there are multiple 'sections' in an assembly file that tell the
computer what each series of 1s and 0s in the resulting executable mean.

One such section is the 'data' section. This contains initialized read/write
data (in some cases it is read-only and read/write has another name).

Another section is the 'text' section. This is read-only and contains the
actual code you are running, converted into binary. Static constants can be put
here, since it is accessible at runtime.

A third section is the 'bss' section. This contains read/write data but is
uninitialized. When the code is setup to be run the computer doesn't have to
worry about copying the data into this section, just making sure that it exists.

Each of these sections will be mapped to some address in memory when the code
runs. This doesn't describe all of the addresses that you will see over the
course of execution however. There are two more!

The "heap" is a name given to memory that your program can specifically ask for
after it starts running. This is useful because your program may not know
exactly how much memory it needs until it gets going.

The "stack" is a name given to memory that your program is given when it starts
to essentially save scratch work. It is where local variables are saved.

Thus we can visualize the memory of a running executable as:

```
|_00_| Program Code
|_01_|
|_02_|
|_03_|
|....|
|_04_| Initialized Memory
|_05_|
|_06_|
|_07_|
|....|
|_08_| Uninitialized Memory
|_09_|
|_10_|
|_11_|
....
|_38_| Dynamic Memory (from malloc)
|_39_|
|_40_|
|_41_|
....
|_96_| Program Stack (local variables)
|_97_|
|_98_|
|_99_|
```

Now lets look at each example.

### Number 1

The buffer was declared inside main's stack. Thus the buffer will likely be
located there (though it is large enough that some compilers may move it
elsewhere). The stack is often in memory near the end of addressible
memory that grows towards the static code.

### Number 2

The buffer was declared in global scope. It was uninitialized, so it can go in
the uninitialized data section. If it was put in the initialized data section
then the operating system would have to initialize all 10kb of memory before
starting the code, which would waste time.

### Number 3

The buffer was declared in global scope, but initialized. It can go in the
initialized data section. The operating system will have to initialize all 10kb
of memory devoted to the buffer to 'a', 'b', 'c', then a bunch of zeroes.

### Number 4

The buffer was declared by asking for more memory, so it will be some block that
the operating system gave it to use.

Note that due to virtual addressing it is likely that the results for numbers
1-3 would be the same each time you ran the code, but this one is almost certain
to change on each execution as the operating system finds different blocks of
memory to give you.

Visualizing all of this we see different addresses:

```
|_00_| Program Code
|_01_|
|_02_|
|_03_|
|....|
|_04_| Initialized Memory
|_05_|
|_06_|
|_07_| <-- Number 3
|....|
|_08_| Uninitialized Memory
|_09_|
|_10_|
|_11_| <-- Number 2
....
|_38_| Dynamic Memory (from malloc)
|_39_|
|_40_|
|_41_| <-- Number 4
....
|_96_| Program Stack (local variables)
|_97_|
|_98_|
|_99_| <-- Number 1
```

Comment: The reason the OS gives different blocks each time you run the program is because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

Comment: Yeah, and the stack would probably be different if you get a different PID. I love it when the comments have the 'more in depth than necessary' stuff. :)

Comment: Why would the stack depend on PID? Before ASLR, every process had the same memory layout.

Comment: In embedded systems each PID often gets its own stack. C is often used on embedded systems.

Comment: Ahh, I generally assume we're talking about user-mode programs on OSes like Unix or Windows, where processes run in virtual memory, unless the question specifically states otherwise

Answer (score 0):

The address of the allocated memory is always different, it depends on the free memory and on what memory range the operating system gives to your program.

EDIT: Consider also that every variable you allocate in a function is allocated in the stack while others are allocated in the heap.

Comment: This does not explain anything about the differences between the four different programs. I think that it therefor somewhat misses the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

For examples 2 and 3, the array is declared globally, i.e. not on the stack during execution. The other two have it declared on the stack while the program is running. These two schemes will have wildly different results. The differences between the results in each pair are more subtle, and are really up to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The text printed from `printf("address: %p\n", buffer);`  could be the same in all for programs (although unlikely) and as demonstrated by OP, they can be different.

Many compilers arrange data in different groups (e.g. segments).  That is a property of the compiler and not C.  These groups are often based on the lifetime of the variable and how (if) it is initialized.

Research your compiler for details.

```
char global_initialized_to_zero[10000];
char global_initialized[10000] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };

int main() {
  char local_uninitialized[10000];
  char* allocated = malloc(10000);
  ...
```